# Why does this combination of get and setdefault not work as expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In the following I would expect `x == True` except `x == False`:

```
k = 'key'
d = dict()
x = d.get(k, not d.setdefault(k, False))

print(d) # {'key': False}
print(x) # False
```

Why does this happen?

In any case, I'd like a method that returns True on the first call, and False otherwise. I guess it's not so hard to implement a class that does this, but I suspect there should be a built-in way.

Tried with Python 3.6 Anaconda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `dict.get()` gets evaluated before the call to `.get()`.  Thus the `setdefault` has already happened. How about:

```
x = d.get(k) or not d.setdefault(k, True)
```

#### Test Code:

```
k = 'key'
d = dict()
x = d.get(k) or not d.setdefault(k, True)

print(d)  # {'key': False}
print(x)  # False
```

#### Results:

```
{'key': True}
False
```